# Angular App with more than one entry point

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

so, i'm writing a really simple application using angular, and i basically just want to be able to route my requests to their respective pages but also use those pages as views such that the following views:

```
-- html
    main-app.ejs
    -- views
        faq.ejs
        about.ejs
        home.ejs
        register.ejs
```

are available by going through the main app, but the user can also get there just by putting in the following respectively:

```
/faq
/about
/home
/register
```

any ideas?

I was thinking something like this could work:

```
app.get('/views/:viewName', routes.view);
app.get('/:app?', routes.app);
```

Where I basically just point the request to the main app, but that doesn't work at all because when the page loads and the following router takes hold:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/home',
        controller: 'sliderController'
    }).when('/faq', {
        templateUrl: '/views/faq',
        controller: 'faqController'
    });
});
```

the default page always loads

Comment: I read the question 3 times and still don't fully understand it. If the user goes to `www.yourapp.com/views/faq` what do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to be able to get to the faq view by typing in the following: someurl.com/faq. I want to get to the about page by typing the following: someurl.com/about how do i do this while using the same application page, such that, all of the same angular code gets sent on the first request, but the first view to be loaded is based on what the user first asked for... does that make sense?